# Lenovo laptop dvd drive not showing in bios setup

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem with my friend laptop lenovo, this laptop dvd drive not detecting and its not showing in bios setup,and device manager also, but its ejecting the door when i press the eject button of the dvd, so what will be the issue .

Comment: Ejecting the door is just a guaranty that the electric part is working, but this doesn't ensure you that the device is fully functional. Is the laptop ever been opened for repair? Is this an old laptop?

Comment: With a vague question, such as this, there are only vague answers. You may find it useful to read **[ask]** to improve your question. That being said, sounds like the DVD drive has failed and needs to be repaired/replaced. Take it to a technician.